# Custom Login jsp + spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I'm just learning all about spring and I was triying to do my own project but instead of use thymeleaf I'll use JSP. I have an example running with spring boot + spring security and it own custom login. I do the same, but instead of html+thymeleaf, I'm using jsp but the custom login is not showing, always appear the default spring security login, any help?

This is the JSP:

```
<!-- Login Form -->
                <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/authenticateTheUser" 
                      method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

                    <!-- Place for messages: error, alert etc ... -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-15">
                            <div>

                                <!-- Check for login error -->

                                <c:if test="${param.error != null}">

                                    <div class="alert alert-danger col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                                        Invalid username and password.
                                    </div>

                                </c:if>

                                <!-- Check for logout -->

                                <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">

                                    <div class="alert alert-success col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                                        You have been logged out.
                                    </div>

                                </c:if>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- User name -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> 

                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span> 

                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" >
                    </div>

                    <!-- Login/Submit Button -->
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="form-group">                       
                        <div class="col-sm-6 controls">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- I'm manually adding tokens ... Bro! -->

                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                           value="${_csrf.token}" />

                </form>
```

The configuration:

```
package com.crm.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // add a reference to our security data source

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("securityDataSource")
    private DataSource securityDataSource;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("aplicando configuracion");
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/employees/showForm*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/employees/save*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/employees/delete").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/showMyLoginPage").permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }



}
```

And the controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/showMyLoginPage")
public String showMyLoginPage() {

    return "fancy-login";

}

// add request mapping for /access-denied

@GetMapping("/access-denied")
public String showAccessDenied() {

    return "access-denied";

}
```

Here you have the link in github
https://github.com/a343/srping

Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: can you add this line `.antMatchers("/showMyLoginPage").permitAll()` after `.antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()` and try ?

Comment: Hi, I did, but not solved the problem. I've added this line "System.out.println("---->>>apply configuration");" to the configure method, and it's not appearing in the log, therefore, for some reason, the configuration is not applied and because of that is not going to the controller and be able to show the custom login, The problem is i dont have any idea why :)

Comment: @AntonioDiaz Can you update your question and show full spring configuration class? Or you can provide your git repo.

Comment: Hi, It's already edited. Thanks